# Is "It is raining or it is not raining." a tautology?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Is the following proposition a tautology:

"It is raining or it is not raining."

I is obviously always true, so one thinks that it should be a tautology. However, i thought a tautology has free variables, which can be replaced by propositions. If then, no matter what proposition we take, the composed composition turns into a true statement, we speak of a tautology.

E.G. $T(A)$ is a tautology, where $T(A):= (A\Rightarrow A)$. So the tautology $T$ depends on A.

However, the sentence "It is raining or it is not raining." doesn't contain a free variable, right?

Comment: It is an *instance* of the tautology : $A \lor \lnot A$.

Comment: So the sentence is no tautology, right? It is a proposition for $A$ being set as the instance "A = It is raining?".
Is that correct?

Comment: But we can also say that every proposition that is an instance (in some natural langugae) of a tautology is itself a tautology ...

Comment: This is not a good example. If the skies are cloudy and one drop of rain falls, is it raining? This is a variety of the sorites paradox. It's like asking if 30 degrees fahrenheit is hot. Is 31 hot? Is 32 hot? At some point, if you keep going up by one degree, it's hot. When exactly does that happen? When does a sporadic drop or two of rain become "it is raining?" I don't think this is a good example to bring out the point you're trying to make. It's often not quite raining and not quite not raining.

Comment: Doesn't "it is raining" implicitly refer to a time and a place? Without these you couldn't even tell whether it is true or false. Aren't these your free variables?

Comment: Also look at similar topic on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables#Natural_language).

Comment: @user4894 It is tacitly assumed that someone is observing the weather. Applying a set of criteria, the observer decides whether it is raining or not raining. The result is denoted in a database as either a $1$ (it is raining) or a $0$ (it is not raining). Of course, in both cases there can be many sub-categories! It is sunny, it is cloudy, it is drizzling etc.

Comment: @M.Wind The observer can also decide that it is neither raining, nor not raining if say we have a few drops of water falling from the sky, but not enough for him/her to classify such as rain.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Exactly. So P = "It is raining" is a poor choice of examples to illustrate the question of the tautology-ness of "P or not-P". A better choice would be P = "2 + 2 = 4", a proposition that is unambiguously either true or false. It is often the case that it is neither raining nor not-raining. In other words P and not-P is not a contradiction, nor is P or not-P a tautology for suitably vague choices of P. This is the essence of the Sorites paradox. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorites_paradox. The underlying problem is vagueness. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vagueness

Comment: @DougSpoonwood + user4894. The Sorites paradox and the vagueness problem belong to philosophy. Nothing wrong with that. It is good fun to discuss this stuff among friends. Meanwhile in the real world continuous signals are being digitized routinely. Thank you, physicists and engineers, for developing standards for CD and DVD. Because I love CDs and DVDs. What a shame if they had not been developed, because of someone's worries about the Sorites paradox.

Comment: @M.Wind The Sorites paradox and vagueness are also issues in logic.  Note the reference to "fuzzy logic" in the Wikipedia on vagueness and the sorites paradox.  Fuzzy logic, which in the broad sense refers to fuzzy mathematics, has many real-world applications.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Sure, a fuzzy logic model (or a neural network) may assign an intermediate value to the question "Is it raining?". It is just another (valid) way of modelling things. It does not disqualify or challenge propositional calculus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course we can "speculate" on philosophy of language issues *ad infinitum*.

**BUT** ... if we agree that *propositional calculus* can provide a very very simplified "model" of natural language, suitable for some limited applications, than we have to consider [see Dirk van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1447145577) (5th ed - 2013), page 5] :

> The linguistic entities occurring in this kind of reasoning are taken to be *sentences*, i.e. entities that express a complete thought, or state of affairs. We call those sentences *declarative*. This means that, from the point of view of natural language, our class of acceptable linguistic objects is rather restricted.
>
> Fortunately this class is wide enough when viewed from the mathematician’s point of view.
>
> The sentences we have in mind are of the kind “27 is a square number”, “every positive integer is the sum of four squares”, “there is only one empty set”.

The *propositional calculus* is based on [see page 7] :

> **Definition 2.1.1** The language of propositional logic has an alphabet consisting of
>
> > (i) proposition symbols: $p_0,p_1,p_2,\ldots$,
> >
> > (ii) connectives: $∧,∨,→,¬,↔,⊥$,
> >
> > (iii) auxiliary symbols: $( , )$.

[...]

> The proposition symbols and $\bot$ stand for the indecomposable propositions, which we call *atoms*, or *atomic propositions*.
>
> [page 15 :] The task of interpreting propositional logic is simplified by the fact that the entities considered have a simple structure. The propositions are built up from rough blocks by adding connectives.
>
> The simplest parts (atoms) are of the form “grass is green”, “Mary likes Goethe”,
>   “$6−3 = 2$”, which are simply *true* or *false*. We extend this assignment of *truth values* to composite propositions, by reflection on the meaning of the logical connectives.

We define *valuation* a mapping $v$ from the set $PROP$ of *atoms* to the set $\{ 0, 1 \}$ of *truth values* :

> > $v : PROP \to \{ 0, 1 \}$.

Thus we have [page 18] :

> **Definition 2.2.4**
>
> > (i) $\varphi$ is a *tautology* if $v(\varphi) = 1$ for all valuations $v$.
> >
> > (ii) $\vDash \varphi$ stands for “$\varphi$ is a *tautology*”.

Thus, according to the truth-functional definition of *connectives* of *classical logic*, we have that :

> > $\vDash p \lor \lnot p$, i.e. : $p \lor \lnot p$ is a *tautology*.

And so :

> > “the grass is green or the grass is not green”

is a natural language's *instance* of the above tautology.

Comment: So, *PO* ( principle of omniscience) is not a tautology in intuitionistic logic, right ?

Comment: @FardadPouran - in *intuitionistic logic* it is not correct to speak of *tautology*, because the "classical" truth-functional definition of conncetives (i.e.the truth-tables) deso not hold. But yes, the formula $p \lor \lnot p$ is **not** intuitionistically *valid*.

Answer (score 0):

There is an implied variable in this proposition, namely the *day* (or hour, etc.) being referred to.  The question whether or not this is a tautology therefore does involve quantification over a domain which is potentially infinite, at least in some obvious formalisations.  Therefore the question whether the proposition is a tautology is a bit more complicated.

This is of course closely related to the law of excluded middle (LEM). If one uses formalisations in classical logic, then of course this is a tautology.  However, if one's background logic is intuitionistic, then it is not a tautology. In certain constructive frameworks one cannot even assume trichotomy, asserting that for every real number $x$ one always has $(x<0)\vee(x=0)\vee(x>0)$.

For a recent discussion see  http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s11787-014-0102-8  To make this a bit more plausible, note that LEM is the basic ingredient in a proof by contradiction. Even classically trained mathematicians recognize that a proof by contradiction can be disappointing because it provides no way of exhibiting the object whose putative "existence" is being proved. This  was of course the basic concern of Kronecker, Brouwer, Errett Bishop, and others.